# Connect with pgAdmin to Postgres container not working

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have looked at all the answers out there to resolve this, but with no success, I have tried the following:

1. Get the IP of container and use it
   [image: ip address retrieved]
   [image]
   [image]
2. Use local IP address (127.0.0.1)
3. Use host.docker.internal
   [image]

I have 2 Postgres containers running, one doesn't have any PORT and IP Address (network is "host") as you can see and the other does (network "birdge" and has IP Address, see the screen shot)

Comment: Show how you started the postgres docker container

Comment: docker run --name my_ps3 -p 5432:5432 --network="bridge" -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test1234 -v postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres

Comment: your `docker ps` of `my_ps2` shows your portfoward is 7676->7676, which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

When you start the docker container, you need to [publish the container's port to the host using `-p`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose). Since you wanted port `7676`, you can do:

`docker run -p 7676:5432 postgres`

And point pgadmin to `localhost:7676`

Comment: I did expose the Address, but still getting this error: docker run --name my_ps3 -p 5432:5432 --network="bridge" -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test1234 -v postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres    and in pdadmin i write hostname as "localhost" and post as "5432" , maintenance database as "postgres", username "postgres" and the password as attached

Comment: don't get fancy with the networking. take out the `network` option. what are the logs on the container?